# How to show/hide textareas in a loop with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, loops

In the following example i have a script with a loop that fetches comments from database, and gives every comment a form with a textarea and submit button so that users can interact with every comment separately.

The follow code makes the page looks a big mess and disturbing due to the repetition of the texareas.

What i need is a jQuery code that will hide the textareas and allow me to show a selected textarea individually when a link or div is clicked. I will simplify what i want in the following code.

```
<?php
$comments = array('comment1','comment2','comment3','comment4','comment5','comment6','comment7','comment8','comment9');
$c_count = count($comments);

for($i=0; $i<$c_count; $i++){
    $comment = $comments[$i];

    echo $comment;
?>
    <hr />

    <div style="border:1px solid #999; width:200px;">Click Here to Show Reply Form</div>

    <div class="comment_box">

        <form action="path/to/insert_reply.php" method="POST">
            <textarea name="reply" cols="47" rows="4"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Reply">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: If you'd like a jQuery answer, show an example of the rendered ('view source') HTML, not the php that generates it.

Comment: i have already posted a link to the rendered HTML, if you mean something else please provide more clarification.

Comment: And when you correct your site's HTML, or that link dies, this question becomes immediately useless to anyone else in the future. Post your relevant code in your question, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/): help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: i got your point, i have removed the link and corrected the html to allow every user to simulate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with JQuery. http://api.jquery.com/ will be helpful.

In this example, the client can click on the comment_header div to view or hide the comment box. Note I added an additional identifier to the divs. There are many different ways to select individual div elements - you might consider wrapping both the comment_header and comment_box divs under a container div with a unique id attribute. Here, I choose to use the .data() JQuery capability.

PHP:

```
<?php
$comments = array('comment1','comment2','comment3','comment4','comment5','comment6','comment7','comment8','comment9');
$c_count = count($comments);

for($i=0; $i<$c_count; $i++){
  $comment = $comments[$i];
  echo $comment;
?>
  <hr />
  <div data-index="<?= $i; ?>" style="border:1px solid #999; width:200px;">Click Here to Show Reply Form</div>
  <div id="<?= $i; ?>" class="comment_box">
    <form action="path/to/insert_reply.php" method="POST">
      <textarea name="reply" cols="47" rows="4"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Reply">
    </form>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.comment_box').hide();
  $('.comment_header').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#' + $(this).data('index')).toggle();
  });
});
```

Hope this is helpful. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EUQG2/

Comment: This might disappoint you, i have been trying to apply your code since you posted it. i use this library http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js , but no action takes place at all! why is that? the javascript works fine if i do something like this 
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".comment_box").hide();

 $(".comment_header").click(function() {
  $(".comment_box").slideToggle(10);
 });

});
but your code does not activate, i'm frustrated..

Comment: It is important to remember that I did alter some of your PHP. Specifically, you should notice the new data-index attribute, the new id attribute, and the new classes I introduce to simplify our DOM selection. Here is some JSFiddle for even further demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/EUQG2/

Comment: it does work on jsfiddle, but not on my computer! do i need to update something? any clues? **EDITED**

Comment: My best guess is that you are trying to run the JavaScript before you have introduced the JQuery script. Make sure you have a <script src="jquery"></script> line BEFORE using the Javascript above.

Comment: The library is the first script source posted iin the header tag, for now i will set your answer as accepted because technically this is what i'm looking for, which is toggling the element based on unique id. do you have other guess on why the code does not work on my computer yet it still works fine on JSFiddle? **EDITED**

Comment: It works now :), thank you so much, thumbs up..it was just a syntax error.

Comment: by the way, the js code you're posting in jsfiddle is the correct one, the one posted in your answer here does not work with me, perhaps you need to edit your answer and replace the code!

Comment: Hooray me first accepted answer. Glad I could help, I've updated my original answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To hide unselected `textarea` when a particular textarea is focused

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').focus(function(){
        $('textarea').not(this).hide();
    });
});
```

You can play around this. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, assuming that all you want to do is to hide the textarea elements (in this case by hiding the parent `.comment_box` element), and to show them by clicking the preceding `div` element:

```
$('.comment_box').hide().prev('div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.comment_box').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TG887/).

If you want only one `.content_box`/`textarea` visible at any given point:

```
$('.comment_box').hide().prev('div').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).next('.comment_box');
    $('.comment_box').not(target).hide();
    target.toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TG887/1/).

References:

- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: This might disappoint you, i have been trying to apply your code since you posted it. i use this library http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js , but no action takes place at all! why is that? the javascript works fine if i do something like this 
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".comment_box").hide();

 $(".comment_header").click(function() {
  $(".comment_box").slideToggle(10);
 });

});
but your code does not activate, i'm frustrated..